# Why I see only about one hundred bounding boxes in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I do not see all bounding boxes in "Images" Tab in the tensorboard. I think tensorboard displays about 100 bounding boxes.

I've set up my pipeline.config acording to [proto definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9bbf8015dba2133ab2343ec6d6b5096033504e36/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto) especially:

```
eval_config {
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 200                                                                   visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  num_visualizations: 200                                                                         }
```

but tensorborad is displaying only part of objects (only 100). 
I visualised evaluation tfrecord outside tensorboard and I see all ground truth bounding boxes (more then 100).

Can anybody point me some direction? Am I missed something?

Comment: Could you also provide your config file here?

Comment: The simple repo that shows the problem is [here](https://github.com/wkoziej/100bboxes)

Answer (score 0):

In config file, there is a field called `post_processing`, and in this field [`max_total_detections`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/4909765543ff0c96627161ecc75eec6c309dbdce/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config#L128) is usually set to 100.

So to make the model predict more, you need to set this field to `max_total_detections : 200` for example.

Debug tips:
[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9bbf8015dba2133ab2343ec6d6b5096033504e36/research/object_detection/model_lib.py#L460) is the part where the evaluation of groundtruth images take place. It created a plotting object. You can print these parameters like `max_examples_to_draw`, `max_boxes_to_draw` to see that they are actually passed to the plotting object. (Because the plotting object will finally visualize groundtruth bboxes on the image).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess the problem is with evaluation, not a prediction. Nevertheless: I'm using faster_rcnn model, so I've tried your suggestion and set `max_detections_per_class: 200` in `model` subsection `second_stage_post_processing` but effect is the same. I don't see all ground truth in tensorboard

Comment: Indeed you are correct. But I don't think this problem is a tensorboard bug, tensorboard only parse tfevents file so a possible case is the evaluation image when  processed, contain 100 plotted bboxes. I've updated the debug tips.